# How to install libraries without sudo?

Tags: c++, linux, qt

I want to run a lengthy computation on a **cluster computer**. The cluster computer has a **Linux OS** and a **compiler** but **no GUI, just a command line**. The problem is that I **cannot use the sudo command** to install additional libraries.

My program is in C++ and uses some **Qt** stuff such as `QString`. It also uses **GSL** and **Eigen** libraries. I am especially worried about the Qt libraries, since the installation seems [nontrivial](http://www.wikihow.com/Install-Qt-SDK-on-Ubuntu-Linux) and the libraries seem very large.

I am making all my development on an Ubuntu OS, but my knowledge of Linux is minimal.

What do you suggest? Have you ever installed Qt "locally"? I can also attempt to refactor Qt out of my program using `std::string` and standard C++ equivalents where possible.

Comment: Question is better suited to unix.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your options are pretty much twofold: Have your system administrator install the libraries in the "normal" location for you, or check the documentation for how to install them in a directory to which you have write access (probably under your home directory) and then link your application against that.

Answer (score 4):

If you have uploaded your shared-object (.so*) libraries to your home directory, modifying your LD_LIBRARY_PATH environment variable[1] might work. On my system, this variable is empty, which indicates that I would add /lib, /usr/lib, and any other default system library paths to this variable first, like

export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/lib/:/usr/lib:/home/user/lib

If LD_LIBRARY_PATH is nonempty, try

export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=${LD_LIBRARY_PATH}:/home/user/lib

1: http://tldp.org/HOWTO/Program-Library-HOWTO/shared-libraries.html

Comment: But can I just take the library from my local Ubuntu system and use it "as is" in a different Linux system?

Comment: The short answer is "yes." 

In practice, shared libraries often link against other shared libraries, meaning that you would need to be sure to copy those as well.

The ldd command will be really useful.